# PlotLegend in one row?

Tags: legending

Simple example

```
leg = {"Sin[a x]....", "Cos[x]....", "Tan[x].....", "Cot[x]....."};
Plot[{Sin[a x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2},PlotLegends -> Placed[leg, Below]]
```

[image]

shows a plot with plotlegend.

I would like to arrange the plotlegend in one row and tried to resize

```
leg = Map[Style[#, 5] &, {"Sin[a x]....", "Cos[x]....", "Tan[x].....", "Cot[x]....."}];
```

without success. The Legends still are arranged in a 2x2 grid!

How can I force the PlotLegend in one row?

Thanks!

Comment: @ Lukas Lang Thanks, `PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[leg, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}], Below]` is the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option for the `LineLegend` which controls this feature:`LegendLayout -> "Row"`. This is, however, not enough. It seems that the legend length should, in addition, fit into the image length. If it does not the legend may be still rearranged into a few lines. It started working as soon as I removed two points from the last two legends. I am not quite sure, however, that it is, indeed, related to the image size. Anyway that's what I see:

```
leg = {"Sin[x]....", "Cos[x]....", "Tan[x]....", "Cot[x]...."};
leg1 = Map[
   Style[#, 5] &, {"Sin[a x]...", "Cos[x]...", "Tan[x]...", 
    "Cot[x]..."}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  ImageSize -> 100*n, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[If[LEG, leg, leg1], LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
    Below]], Control[{n, 1, 8}], Control[{LEG, {True, False}}]]
```

[image]

Have fun!